# Link click form submit and go to link together

Tags: html, forms

I have form like this

```
<form name="test_form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="demo">
    <a href="google.com">Link</a>
</form>
```

I want to submit that form by clicking the link and as well as go to that link(google.com) too .

How can I do this ? 
I can submit the form by clicking the link but can't do it together .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect on the server

for example in PHP:

```
<?PHP
$url = $_POST["url"]; // you need to clean this
// save whatever here
header("Location: ".$url);
?>

<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("submitLink").onclick=function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    document.getElementById("url").value=this.href;
    form.submit();  
    return false; // cancel link
  }
}
</script>
<form id="myForm" action="saveandredirect.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="somefieldname" value="demo">
  <input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value="">
</form>
<a href="http://google.com" id="submitLink">Link</a>
```